# R: Plotting standard deviation against sample size n

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to plot sample size against standard deviation in R but keep getting the error: 
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

```
powrange <- seq(0, 200, 10)
n <- sapply(powrange, function(i) power.t.test(power=1-0.1,sd=i,delta=8)$n)
plot(n, powrange, type="b",xlab="Sample size",ylab="Standard deviation")
```

Comment: I already get an error at the second line of code.

Comment: It seems that the function does not work for `i=0`. Changing the first line to `powrange <- seq(10, 200, 10)` gives me a plot.

Comment: Thanks Roland and that worked Stibu, cheers!  From a statistics/function point of view, do you think I should instead have Sample size on the y axis and Standard deviation on the x axis since it is the Standard deviation I am changing?